# Best option to save the session state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension that will use as the authentication method the id of facebook, twitter, or google+ (maybe three). Once user authentication occurs, what is the best option to save the session state to closure? Is using cookies? Any field within a content script?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "session state," but you can use gapi.auth.setToken() to store user credentials. Learn more at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken.

Comment: Thank you. I tested with Google's JavaScript library for its APIs and I have no problem to use it on an extension, since the field Redirect URI does not redirect to the extension. I meant if it was better to use cookies, localStorage or other storage medium in the state of the browser client session.